# Handle multiple request in webapi method which internally access a database

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api2

We are serving multiple clients request using webapi, which is hosted on iis server.

How will the iis handle thousands of request, from clients?

1) How can we achieve best performance in this scenario ?
2) Will making webapi method, async will make any difference?
3) What are the best practices, that we need to follow ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IIS launches a thread from a thread pool to handle your request. 
1) By not using iis and webapi? If you have to, get the best hardware
2) `async` methods will only improve performance if the work is io blocking (e.g. you are waiting on network or disk reads)
3) http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/important-steps-to-increasing-web-api-performance/

Comment: Thanks for such quick response. 1) By not using iis and webapi? If you have to, get the best hardware -- OK  2) async methods will only improve performance if the work is io blocking (e.g. you are waiting on network or disk reads) -- yes there are db level calls.

Answer (score 1):

> How will the iis handle thousands of request, from clients?

It depends. Actually, even the limitation of IIS might not be your major concern, there are other things that might affect IIS performance, like for example the hardware.

> How can we achieve best performance in this scenario ?

You can do many things, you can use queue system, there is no need to make the user wait for a heavy transaction or very complex logic in many scenario. If the request of the user involve many different complex tasks you can do the minimum and return to the user and the rest can be done in the background. You can use a queue system for such scenario.

> Will making webapi method, async will make any difference?

No, because `async` means 'This method is allowed to work asynchronously' or 'This method is allowed to use `await` operator'. You should know how to use `concurrency` not just `asynchronous programming`. But using `Tasks` for heavy transaction like dealing with the database and `await`ing these Tasks in `async` methods, Yes, this will help your server respond to more requests at the same time.

> What are the best practices, that we need to follow

A good understanding of the `concurrency` will be very helpful. Also, it's not just about the `WEB API` everything might affect your web application performance from the Data Access layer, to the indexes in the `RDBMS` even the response might contribute. Like if your response is `XML` you may use `JSON` because it generates relatively less data than `XML` thus faster data exchange. Your question is very broad and it really depends. It is not just about `IIS` or the `Web API` or even the whole `Web application`, it depends.

Comment: Thanks for such quick response.  1) How can we achieve a queuing system, in case of webapi terminology? 2) We are dealing with heavy database transaction, in each client request. In every response data is returned as per client request. 3) We are using json format instead of xml.

Answer (score 0):

You need a good understanding of `Concurrency` for this.
Above answer explains it in the best way.
Also, you can go through this MSDN article for more in-depth detail about `concurrency`

[Handling Concurrency with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)